# Advice! JavaScript error management in different browsers?

Tags: javascript, function, cross-browser, prototype, polyfills

I'm working on some new (pure) JavaScript functions like this:

```
exampleName.prototype.html = function(value){
 return this.each(function(){
  var object = this;
  this.innerHTML = value;
 });
};
```

I know that this example will work perfectly fine in most browsers but lets just say for the sake of this question that this particular example does not work on ie6+
First I want to check if it works on ie6+ and if it does not I want the browser to run another set of code (like some poly fill code)
how do I state this:

```
exampleName.prototype.html = function(value){
 return this.each(function(){
  var object = this;
  if(this Works On Ie6+){
   this.innerHTML = value;
  }else if(this Does Not Work On Ie6+){
   // poly fill code to make it work on ie6^
  }
 });
};
```

This is one of the methods I've tried:

```
exampleName.prototype.html = function(value){
 return this.innerHTML = value && this.innerHTML = valueWithPolyfill;
};
```

and this is another:

```
exampleName.prototype.html = function(value){
 return this.innerHTML = value || this.innerHTML = valueWithPolyfill;
};
```

I've tried it a couple of ways but still failed or the code will run twice or three times...
thanks in advance,- Millzie.

Comment: I think generally, when writing polyfills, it is recommended to not rely on browser detection, but rather feature detection. Check to see if the "native" functions that you are relying on in your newly defined functions exist in the browser, and then branch out your code based on the results of the checks.

Comment: http://modernizr.com/

Comment: @jared no more delicious frameworks and libs for me... Just pure JavaScript from now on, but thanks.

Comment: Why would you ignore all frameworks and libs?  I mean I guess if you like to pretend its 1999 that is cool... but... why? LOL

Comment: What is "pure" javascript? There is ECMAScript, which consists of a number of built–in objects and functions and from which you can construct additional native objects and functions, and there are also host objects and methods that are implementation dependant (such as JavaScript and JScript) but may follow some other specification (such as W3C DOM Core). Then there are libraries and frameworks, usually constructed from a combination of ECMAScript and host features.

Comment: @Phatjam (nice name lamo) i made the one mistake every newbie makes i learnt jquery not JavaScript and by learning jquery i did not understand how JavaScript worked. Compared to other Languages I've learned I've spent the most time in JavaScript. About 8 months and I'm still not a master...

Comment: @RobG bro you understood me wrong. By pure JavaScript i meant I'm not using any add ons or plugins no libs no frameworks.

Comment: @Millzie—Ok. There are many articles on feature detection, check out [*Browser Detection (and What to Do Instead)*](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/detect-browser/).

Comment: Right. No libraries but someone tell me how to do it. Hmm. (There's also https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim)

Comment: @JaredFarrish—I think that's a pretty reasonable request. The OP wants to understand how to do something, which is the first step in being able to determine whether library A or B is the better choice, or even required for a particular thing.

Comment: @RobG - I didn't say it was, but if you want to know *how* it's done, check how *others have done it*. Not all of the libraries out there are as esoterically written as jQuery.

Comment: @Millzie I learned jQuery initially as I got into JavaScript as well.  jQuery is just a collection of JavaScript functions to make using JavaScript less wordy.  I can understand using base JS functions if you are trying to get performance boosts or if you don't want to include an entire library which bloats your codebase when only using one function from the library.  But libraries like jQuery, or modernizr make life so much simpler because they contain solid, cross browser solutions to problems exactly like this.